# Json enumeration of types not listed

Tags: json, json.net

I am attempting to formalize a json string that describes polymorphic types into keyvalue pair listings using NewtonSoft's `JToken`. At the beginning of the json it lists the types as an enumeration.

```json
"$types":{
   "AIDataModels.LanguageModels.ProtoLanguageModels.RootDescriptor, AIDataModels, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null":"1",
   "AIDataModels.LanguageModels.ProtoLanguageModels.MicroDescriptor, AIDataModels, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null":"2",
   "AIDataModels.LanguageModels.ProtoLanguageModels.ProtoAttribute, AIDataModels, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null":"3",
   "AIDataModels.LanguageModels.ProtoLanguageModels.EnumElement, AIDataModels, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null":"4",
   "AIDataModels.LanguageModels.ProtoLanguageModels.EnumClass, AIDataModels, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null":"5",
   "AIDataModels.Summaries.ClassSummary, AIDataModels, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null":"6",
   "AIDataModels.Summaries.GeneralizeTypeSummary, AIDataModels, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null":"7"
}
```

There however areas where a field is listed and its type is not referenced, so for example here's a listing of when it does reference the type:

```json
"GeneralizedType":{
   "$type":"4",
   "IsComposite":false,
   "Parent":{
      "$type":"5",
      "Key":"features",
      "Numeral":1
   },
   "Key":"part",
   "Numeral":29
}
```

And here's where it does not:

```json
"GeneralizedType":{
   "$i":6
}
```

Also, here's an example of a type being cited, 7, but the field `GenerailizedType` doesn't have a reference enumerator:

```json
{
   "$type":"7",
   "GeneralizedType":{
      "$i":14
   },
   "Count":2
}
```

I realize that the json parser is removing redundancy but I'm clueless as to how to find these "$i" values within the json string to a type. What am I missing?

Comment: I think your json serializer config contains `ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore` option. So your json converter doesn't convert looped references for preventing infinite loops.

Comment: Let me add that de-serializing to the intended type works fine, all the fields and object types are correct. Its just when I'm iterating over the json with JToken that I can't resolve the "$i" values.

Comment: It's not clear from your question where your problem is.  Can you [edit] your question to share some code that does not work -- i.e. a [mcve]?  E.g. if your JSON is lacking some properties you expect to be present, we would need to see how the JSON is **created** to help you.

Comment: I did show where the type in the json is not resolve to any enumeration.  The RootDescriptor class was serialized by FastJson. That json does work when de-serialization is performed, that's not my issue.

Comment: My issue is that when I'm reading the json using JToken to get KeyValue pair listings, not to de-serialize the json,  I run into the "$i" values for GenerializedType where I have no way of reading the fields of the class of Generalized type.  Since the json is valid json and can be de-serialized by any json parser the json encoding is not the problem.  What I would like to know is how to resolve those "$i" values to find the field names and values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "$i" values are actually listings from the object type from an assembly that a json parser creates, so without the assembly to de-serialize from those entries there isn't a means to decoded them.